# how do I want to sum all the stocks based on distinct attributes

Tags: mysql

I want to display attributes and sum all stocks of each attribute with **DISTINCT**.
like

```
+----------+----------+
|    attr  |   stock  |
+----------+----------+
|    Blue  |    61    |
|    Red   |    119   |
+----------+----------+
```

this is my table1

```
+----------+----------+
| attrid   |attribute |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |    Blue  |
|        2 |    Blue  |
|        3 |    Red   |
|        4 |    Red   |
+----------+----------+
```

this is my table2

```
+----------+----------+
|   stock  | attrid   |
+----------+----------+
|     40   |    1     |
|     21   |    2     |
|     45   |    3     |
|     74   |    4     |
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Join the two tables, sum the stock column, and group by the attribute ID like this.

```
select sum(B.stock), A.attribute
from table1 A 
inner join table2 B on (A.attrid = B.attrid)
group by A.attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe instead of `DISTINCT` try `GROUP BY`

demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mZHvGeE4d4qs3N2jd5LbD3/0

```sql
SELECT SUM(t2.stock) AS sum_stock, t1.attribute
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.attrid = t2.attrid
GROUP BY t1.attribute
```